# How can I wait for this request (ajax or js) that doesn't refresh the page with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Using NodeJS and puppeteer

I'm having a hard time waiting for an element that will come with information I need, but it may not exist either.

I tried with

```
   try {
     await page.waitForSelector(selector, { timeout: 1500 });
     let element = await page.$(selector);
     price = await page.evaluate((el) => el.textContent, element);
   } catch(error) {
     console.error(error);
   }
```

But it did not work

I tried with

```
     await page.waitForFunction(
       `document.getElementById("PlaceHolderMain_lblCodigoProdutoValor").innerText != "${codWillChange}"`,
       { timeout: 1500 }
     );
```

The code does not wait, it passes in one go

I know that when clicking on the button, a request is made, but it doesn't refresh the page (if I couldn't get it, waiting for the page to load until the end), it's done with ajax (**the page is made in asp.net**)

**How can I wait for this request (ajax or js) that doesn't refresh the page?**

In page have a function (that replace click of button), but I don't know if help

> The idea is to optimize as much as possible, and not wait for a team
> that I can is wasting time
>
> The execution of the function occurs on average with 700ms
>
> But it also reaches 1.2s
>
> I put 2s to guarantee per hour
>
> But I'll waste a lot of time "unnecessarily"

Comment: Did you try `waitForResponse`? It's hard to help otherwise without seeing the page and a [mcve] of your code, with a clear description of what you're [really trying to accomplish (there may be a better way to do it than you think)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).

Comment: The page is with access (login and password) unfortunately ☹️.
I could maybe make a page like what I want to fetch data
But it would basically be a page with a button, which by clicking fetches information from a server, and brings it up without refreshing the page or anything

Comment: About waitForResponse, I will try!

Comment: A button that fires a request with zero updates to the UI sounds like a pretty poor user experience. This is a rarity indeed. But still, `waitForResponse` should be able to handle it. And if it can't, there's also `page.on("response", res => {})` which can be promisified (`waitForResponse` is basically a promisified, one-shot `page.on("response", ...)`).

Comment: Really site is not very friendly 
But I have to scrape dice give it

Comment: For now I'm doing this:
After the click I wait for all the requests to load

``await Promise.all([
                page.click("#PlaceHolderMain_btnConfirmar"),
                page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle0" }),
              ]);``